# R - calculate confidence interval of grouped data

Tags: r

Suppose you have a dataset named `data` as follows:

```
Gender Pneumonia_Incidence lower_CI upper_CI
Male   38000               30000    44000
Female 34000               32000    38000
```

I would now like to calculate the total pneumonia incidence, which can be done easily:

```
sum(data$Pneumonia_Incidence)
```

But how can I calculate lower and upper CI for this estimate? Is it valid to just sum `lower_CI` and `upper_CI` values or would I need to do something else?

Comment: "would I need to do something else"  No, that should work. But consider that there is not **one** conf. interval, but infinitely many. Most often we use the 95% conf. int. It's always better to explicitly state which quantile we are looking at.

Comment: @dario that's not right. If you collected a sample of size n, and m were positive, then the rate would be estimated at m/n, and the 95% confidence interval would be m +/- 1.96 * sqrt(((m/n)*(1 - m/n))/n).

Comment: @dario for example, if I sample 100 people and find 10 positives, then the estimated incidence per 100,000 would be 10,000 (95% CI 5,163 - 18,035).  But if I sampled 200 and found 20 positives, then the estimated incidence per 100,000 is 10,000 (95% CI 6,366 - 15,230). If the results here are incidence per 100,000 men and incidence per 100,000 women, simply adding the results would give the incidence per _200,000_ people, with the wrong confidence interval.

Comment: @Allan Cameron: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding OPs question: But if we calculate tot **total** incidence as `sum(data$Pneumonia_Incidence)` why is the analogue wrong for its CIs?? We are not talking about a rate, but total numbers!? But I will delete my comment if you insist that I am misunderstanding the question. Thank's for your input anyways.

Comment: @dario since there is a confidence interval, I assume the incidence is based on a sample of a population, and multiplied to give the incidence per 100,000 or per million. It would be very odd to want to add these to get the rate per 200,000 (or per 2 million). Hopefully the OP can clarify with what exactly they are trying to do, rather than both of us being led astray by an incomplete example! We're both just trying to help...

Comment: @Allan Cameron. Thank you for your patience ;) I agree, the example is incomplete and my interpretation/usage of the CI is not as I'd normally use CIs. I  might have been led astray by @J.Doe 's remark: `which can be done easily: sum(data$Pneumonia_Incidence)` ....

Comment: The current data that was provided to me contains raw numbers, not rates per 100,000

Comment: Moreover, the source from which the data was provided to me doesn't specify if the CIs are 95% or 99% but I am assuming they are 95%

Comment: @J.Doe if they are raw numbers, what can it mean to have a confidence interval?

Comment: @J.Doe is the incidence per country? Incidence in the whole world?

Comment: My first thought was that they are values from a model/simulation of some sorts. But we'd need definitively additional information to give a qualified answer (as illustrated by @Allan Cameron s comments)

Comment: The data relates to incidence in some specific subnational regions, but I can't provide the information on which ones. 

A sample of the inhabitants of that region were monitored for pneumonia (and other diseases, pneumonia here was just an example) and this data was used to estimate the number of inhabitants in the whole population (i.e., that whole region) who have pneumonia. However, the data is not expressed as occurrences per 100,000 inhabitants - it is expressed as the absolute number of inhabitants that are expected to have gotten pneumonia

Comment: In that case, it is not incidence per 100,000 but incidence per (whatever the population size is), but the maths still stands.

Comment: You can add the incidences, but not the confidence intervals.

Comment: @AllanCameron So would you say in this case that I cannot in any way infer about what would the CI for the added total be?

Comment: If you can get the original sample sizes and raw number positives then you can do it. Otherwise, I don't think so. Perhaps you should ask over at Cross Validated, the statistics Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @AllanCameron: I'm so sorry (and feel free to ignore me if to annoying): But now I don't understand your reasoning: They took samples and came up with two rates and CIs (one for men and women each). Then they used this rates and CIs to predict incidents in a given population. They now represent total per N inhabitants (**not** per N men or N women). Why can't we add them up? Again, sorry if I'm appearing to be a bit dim.

Comment: @dario because there is a 0.025 probability of the lower confidence interval estimate for women being the actual rate for women and a 0.025 probability of the lower confidence interval for men being the actual rate for men, so the probability of the actual rate being the sum of the lower confidence intervals is the product of these two probabilities, not their mean.

Comment: @AllanCameron: Thanks a bunch! I think I finally understand what you were saying the whole time! The probability of two things with probability B being true at the same time is not B but B * B! And an upper/lower CI is a thing that has a prob. < 1... That's why I can't just add them (or by summing them I now have a new CI, not the 0.025 - 0.975 one...)

Comment: @dario thanks - sorry I wasn't clearer earlier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I calculate lower and upper CI for this estimate?

You cannot with the information you have provided. You would need to know the variance of each estimated prevalence. This must be known since someone *has* calculated the confidence intervals. With these you could then obtain a pooled estimate for the total variance and then calculate the overall confidence interval.

If this is important to you, I strongly suggest you consult a qualified statistician, or at least a reputable text book. This is not simple high school math. There may be other issues such as sampling weights involved. I certainly wouldn't seek statistical advice here, and probably not even at that other place often mentioned. What if your boss asked you how you calculated the confidence interval? Would you say that you consulted the internet?

> Is it valid to just sum lower_CI and upper_CI values ...

No. Variances involve sample sizes. Consider this. Imagine two groups, one with a very large sample size and one with a very small one. The group with the large sample size will have a narrower confidence interval than the group with the small sample size will. If you just added the two intervals, you would end up with an overall interval that was equally weighted by both groups, which intuitively doesn't seem correct. It's a *biased* estimate.

> ... or would I need to do something else?

Consult a statistician. :)